# Differences between Abstract Factory Pattern and Factory Method,confused by one case

Tags: abstract-factory, factory-method

The main difference between a "factory method" and an "abstract factory" is that the factory method is a single method, and an abstract factory is an object. But, sometimes I can't say what it is,for example

```
class Product{

}
interface Facotory{
    public Product create();
}

class FactoryA implements Facotory{
public Product create() {
    return null;
}   
}

class FactoryB implements Facotory{
    public Product create() {
    return null;
    }
}
```

Can you tell me it is factory method or abstract factory?Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739611/differences-between-abstract-factory-pattern-and-factory-method?rq=1

Comment: I know it, but I can't find my answer what i need.@Juan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, Your current example above is Factory Method.

As you have defined an interface (Factory) with a factory method (create) that allows sub classes (FactoryA and FactoryB) to decide which class to instantiate (Product derived classes).

Comment: Does that answer your question, if yes mark it answer. If you have follow up question post it.