# Mistakes in realization of factory pattern java

Tags: java, factory-pattern

I've read this topic with the instruction about how to use factory pattern
[factory pattern dynamic approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235877/factory-pattern-dynamic-approach)

I have this in my factory

```
public class FilterFactory {
    static Map<String, Class> creators;

    static {
        creators = new HashMap<>();
    }
    /*...*/
}
```

And this is one of the classes, which I want to put in the factory

```
public class ExtentionFilterSerializer implements FilterSerializer {
    static {
            FilterFactory.creators.put(".", ExtentionFilterSerializer.class);
    }
    /*...*/
}
```

When I try to use factory in the program, I see that Map is empty. What did I do wrong?

Comment: How do you use the factory?

Comment: I guess you may want to read "Service Provider" in Java instead of reinventing the wheel

Comment: @AdrianShum I think a link would be useful here.

Comment: @Axel I have already given the keyword, it shouldn't be anything difficult to Google it and pick up whatever suitable to oneself

Comment: @AdrianShum I had to look myself, and the right link is somewhat down the list. I think it should be [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html) one, right?  There came lots of links about outdated docs first.

Comment: Yup.  This is the first result when I googled "Java service provider"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For code related:**

The static block to register your class `ExtentionFilterSerializer` will execute if only if this unit `ExtentionFilterSerializer` is realized on classpath. If you haven't used this class `ExtentionFilterSerializer` anywhere in your program, this class wont be loaded, hence the static registration.

Adding a `Class.forname("ExtentionFilterSerializer")` to your client application will fix the load issue.

**Regarding approach used:**

The objective of using a Factory pattern is to determine and create an instance of concrete object type especially when the application cannot determine that at compile time. By adding a static initializer to dynamically register your concrete class, your Factory know of its existence, but still cannot determine which concrete class to use.

Besides, the registration part `FilterFactory.creators.put(".", ExtentionFilterSerializer.class);` should never be in `ExtentionFilterSerializer`, but in a client program.

Another variant of a Factory design pattern makes the creation method abstract (not same as AbstractFactory pattern). A concrete object can be created using those concrete Factory classes, which looks close to your case. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: This works but it's very bad form to encourage use of a static initializer block in the `ExtentionFilterSerializer` class. Can you suggest another solution, without that static block?

Answer (score 0):

`static` blocks are (at least in my experience) not very reliable in terms of execution. You have no direct control over when the `static` block of `ExtentionFilterSerializer` is executed.

I'd rather implement an `init()` method, so you can explicitly call `ExtentionFilterSerializer.init()` (maybe even add an argument telling the method to which factory this one should be added).

I just worked with a similar construction and `static` blocks were very unreliable resulting in me placing them in a controlled `init()` function, which is called early. From this point in time, you can be sure that your factory and your `ExtentionFilterSerializer` are properly initialized.

Edit: Post below me explains in detail what happens. Either implement a `init()` or make sure your class is actually somewhere.