# How to correctly apply factory method to the DAO factory?

Tags: java, dao, factory

In **[the documentation about DAO](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html)** says:

> When the underlying storage is not subject to change from one
>   implementation to another, this strategy can be implemented using the
>   Factory Method pattern to produce a number of DAOs needed by the
>   application. The class diagram for this case is shown in Figure 9.3.

The figure 9.3 itself:

[image]

What causes misunderstanding is how we can ever apply *factory method* to produce the *number* of `DAO`s? As far as I understood in the case the DAO might be look like

```
public interface DAOFactory{

    public DAO1 getDAO1();
    public DAO2 getDAO2();

}
```

But it would be not a factory method. It would be an abstract factory, because we're producing a family of objects rather than a single object. Couldn't you exlain what they meant when said

> this strategy can be implemented using the
>   *Factory Method pattern* to produce a number of DAOs needed by the
>   application. The class diagram for this case is shown in Figure 9.3.

Comment: The DAOFActory shoudl have 1 method like this public DAOBaseClass getDAO(BaseEntity entity) which returns DAO instance for each entity

Comment: Well ... Your interface `DAOFactory` is an [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) that declares two [factory methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: @StanislavL So what did they mean when they talked about the Factory method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. It is misleading. 
The Image depicting the use of *Factory method* is certainly an example of the *Abstract Factory* design pattern. There's just only one implementation of the factory.

There is a good explanation on the difference between a Factory Method and Abstract Factory here: [Differences between Abstract Factory Pattern and Factory Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739611/differences-between-abstract-factory-pattern-and-factory-method)

The diagram shown in the documentation depicts the *Abstract Factory* pattern.

I can imagine the following use of *DAOs* and *Factory Method*

```
// the Service contains the business logic and uses DAOs to access data
class BaseService {

   public Object doSomething() {
       return getDao().retrieveObject("identifier");
   }

   // Factory method producing DAOs
   public IDao getDao() {
       return new BaseDao();
   }

}

// The DAO interface
interface IDao {
    Object retrieveObject(String identifier);
}


// Another Service that overwrite the type of produced DAOs 
class SmartService extends Service {

   // overwrite the factory method
   public IDao getDao() {
       return new SmartDao();
   }
}
```