# Best way to future proof software that opens files with default application interactively

Tags: vb.net, excel, class, import, module

I have created a `VB .NET` application that opens files in their default application - extracts information and returns it to a listview on a form.

All of the code is in my main form.  The main form has in it

- `Imports Microsoft.Office.Core`
- `Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`
- `Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

If in the future I want to modify my software to include another filetype not thought of in this release, am I better off for all of the filetypes I wish to open (including office) adding new classes for each filetype and including the 'Imports' in the individual classes?

So for example I would have:

- OpenFileDWG.vb
- `Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime`
- OpenFileDOC.vb
- `Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`

etc. etc.
Is this a standard approach?  If I were to do this, could I use:

`If exists LCase(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(Filepath).Extension) THEN
strFileOpener = OpenFileDWG & Extension
Private fileOpener As strFileOpener`

Would this approach work, or would I still need to reference the .dll in the main application, making this approach unworthy?

If I were to use this approach, could I just give the .vb file as part of an update?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Seems to me like the [factory design pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx) is what you need. Separate the different file types to different classes, and have them all implement a basic interface (open file, read content, etc`). Then create an abstract factory class and a concrete factory for each class (meaning for each file type). to enable new file types add-ins you can use [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to load the concrete classes.

Comment: 'Best practice' questions are mostly off-topic for Stack Overflow as they attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Thankyou Zohar - that is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.

Comment: Hi Cybermonkey.  Sorry, I thought it was a reasonable question to ask, although I realise a best-practice / advice question was going to be subjective.  Sometimes though, this can draw answers that open up other avenues to explore not previously thought of.  I will bear it in mid in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like a classing case to use [factory design pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx)

Basically, the factory design pattern provides [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) between the factory created classes and the class that uses them.

Begin by separating the different file types to different classes, and have them all inherit a basic abstract class (`MustInherit` in vb.net).
Then create an factory class to create create the concrete implementation of every file reader class. (meaning for each file type).

I'll try to illustrate with a simple example:

```
'' Defines an abstract class that all FileReaders should inherit
Public MustInherit Class FileReader
   Public MustOverride Function ReadFileContent(Path As String) As String
End Class
```

Now, all of the classes for reading files must inherit the FileReader class:

```
Public Class WordFileReader
   Inherits FileReader

   Public Override Function ReadFileContent(Path As String) As String
   '' TODO: Add code to read the content of the word document and return it as a string.
   End Function
End Class

Public Class ExcelFileReader
   Inherits FileReader

   Public Override Function ReadFileContent(Path As String) As String
   '' TODO: Add code to read the content of the excel file and return it as a string.
   End Function
End Class
```

Then you can use a simple factory method ([read here to learn about the difference between factory methods and abstract factories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739611/differences-between-abstract-factory-pattern-and-factory-method)) to create your classes:

```
Enum FileTypes
    Word,
    Excel
End Enum

Public Function GetFileReader(FileType As FileTypes) As FileReader
    Dim FileReader as FileReader = Nothing
    Select case FileType
        Case FileTypes.Word:
            FileReader = New WordFileReader()
        Case FileTypes.Excel:
            FileReader = New ExcelFileReader()
    End Select
    Return FileReader 
End Function
```

To enable new file types add-ins you can use [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to load the concrete classes.

Comment: Zohar - thank you again for taking the time to provide a detailed explanation.  This is the approach I thought I needed, but was not aware of  'Factory Design Patterns'.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Not a problem, but the way to show appreciation in SO is to upvote an answer or accept it (Only if it actually provides the solution to your problem!)

Comment: Thanks.  I have accepted your answer as it is what I will use to implement the functionality I require.  Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation (story of my life) to upvote your answer though :-(

Comment: Not a problem, to me the 10 reputation points wouldn't matter all that much. The reason you should accept an answer is so that other people will know that the problem is solved, thus saving time for people that might want to answer the question and also helping other people that might encounter a similar problem.