# Factory method pattern - when should the 'Creator' class implement the Factory method?

Tags: java, factory-method

In `Factory method` pattern there are **2 lead implementation** (correct me if I'm wrong):

When `Creator` class is being `abstract` and not providing an implementation for the `Factory method`:

```
public abstract class CasinoGameCreator {

public void playGame() {
    ICasinoGameType gameType = createGame();
    gameType.play();
}

public abstract ICasinoGameType createGame();
```

**Or**, we can have the `Creator` class be a concrete class that provides implementation  for the `Factory method`:

```
public class CasinoGame {

    public static CasinoGame createGame(GameType type) {
        if (type == GameType.BlackJack) {
            return new BlackJackGame();
        } else if (type == GameType.Poker) {
            return new PokerGame();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any strong preference when to use each implementation? if there is, in what general situations we whould prefer using the 1st approach over the 2nd?

Comment: I believe you're referring to the [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/intro-design-patterns-abstract) and the [Factory Method Pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/gof-design-patterns-factory-me). Possible answers to your question on SO [can be found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739611/differences-between-abstract-factory-pattern-and-factory-method)

Comment: Your second example is not a [Factory Method Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern.html), but a [Factory Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html). Did you actually intend to compare two different patterns? Or did you misunderstand what the two options for Factory *Method* Pattern is?

Comment: @Andreas - I was sure they are the same `Factory Method pattern`, so I guess I misunderstood, though the 2nd example are took from _Cracking the coding, 6th edition_ book, so this is very strange to me...

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is following the [Open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). This means: it is open for extensions (as different subclasses can implement different ways of creating a game); but it is closed for modification - the behavior of playGame() is fixed. Well, it is not; but if you use this pattern, you really would want to make playGame() to be final. If you have such an abstract class with an implementation X; and an abstract method Y (used within the other method X); than it doesn't much sense to allow subclasses to change X.

Option 2 is helpful when you are really sure about the different type of games; meaning: chances that this enum will ever change are small. Given the idea of games in casino; I very much doubt that this would be true here. Probably you could add a new game every other day. And then, you have to turn to each place that switches over the GameType and adapt that code.

So, given those thoughts, option 1 would be the first choice - because you can simply add a new game type by creating a new subclass of your creator class. This means: you can add a new game without touching the code responsible for **other** games.

Of course: if you would pick a different example, the requirements might be different, and then option 2 might have certain benefits.