# why we need abstract factory when we already have concrete factories

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

this is the article

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328373/Understanding-and-Implementing-Abstract-Factory-Pa

I don't know why we need to have an abstract factory like `IPhoneFactory`, in the client's end, can't we do sth like

```
class PhoneTypeChecker
{
   ISmart sam;
   IDumb htc;
   //IPhoneFactory factory;    get rid of this abstract factory
   MANUFACTURERS manu;

   ...
   public void CheckProducts()
    {
        switch (manu)
        {
            case MANUFACTURERS.SAMSUNG:
                Console.WriteLine(new SamsungFactory().GetSmart().Name()); 
                Console.WriteLine(new SamsungFactory().GetDumb().Name());               
                break;
            case MANUFACTURERS.HTC:
                Console.WriteLine(new HTCFactory().GetSmart().Name());  
                Console.WriteLine(new HTCFactory().GetDumb().Name());               
                break;
            case MANUFACTURERS.NOKIA:
                Console.WriteLine(new NokiaFactory().GetSmart().Name()); 
                Console.WriteLine(new NokiaFactory().GetDumb().Name());                
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(manu.ToString() + ":\nSmart Phone: " + 
        factory.GetSmart().Name() + "\nDumb Phone: " + factory.GetDumb().Name());
    }
}
```

the only thing I can think of to use `IPhoneFactory` is that we needs to get two different types(Smart and Dumb) from concrete factory classes, but it only save some keystrokes, isn't it?

Comment: You're not wrong - but think about the disadvantages of your approach: the set of types your `PhoneTypeChecker` can produce is now fixed and cannot be extended at runtime. If you want to add a new manufacturer at runtime you can't - you have to edit your source and rebuild it.

Comment: @Dai   if I use `IPhoneFactory factory`, I still need to edit the source (PhoneTypeChecker.cs) with 'case MANUFACTURERS.HUAWEI ...' and rebuild it?

Comment: I suggest starting off with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739611/what-are-the-differences-between-abstract-factory-and-factory-design-patterns

Answer (score 2):

There is a central problem with the article you linked to which means it does not give a good example of how an abstract factory can be used to make an application more extensible:

The problem is that both `enum Manufacturers` and `class PhoneTypeChecker.CheckProducts` have to be aware of *all* types of manufacturers. This almost entirely defeats the purpose of the abstract factory pattern (unless you interpret `CheckProducts()` as an "abstract-factory-factory" method - in which case [welcome to Enterprise Java hell](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/AbstractSingletonProxyFactoryBean.html).

...but if we make a few tweaks to the composition, the advantages become clear.

First, remove `enum MANUFACTURER` (which shouldn't be capitalized anyway) and `CheckProducts` and replace it with an `IManufacturerRepository` .

- **Important note**: If you're actually writing real-code that interfaces with an ORM, then **do not** make your own Repository types because your ORM provides the repository for you. This is especially true with Entity Framework. Especially avoid the "generic repository" anti-pattern.

The `IManufacturerRepository` should only have a single implementation (or a separate one for testing/mocking).

```
public interface IManufacturerRepository
{
    List<IManufacturer> GetManufacturers();
}

public interface IManufacturer
{
    String        Name         { get; }
    IPhoneFactory PhoneFactory { get; } // <-- this is the abstract factory
}
```

Then the `PhoneTypeChecker` can receive the `IManufacturer` via constructor argument:

- I note that this example is silly because there's no meaningful instance state mutation inside `PhoneTypeChecker` nor does `PhoneTypeChecker` represent any kind of operation represented by an abstract type or interface - this would be better done by making `CheckProducts` a `static` method that accepts `IManufacturer` as an parameter).
- In the original article, the `CheckProducts` method does mutate `PhoneTypeChecker`'s state (by setting `factory`, `sam`, `htc`) but *this is a bad design* - because it's really just initializing itself, which should be done inside the constructor - but I digress.

Anyway:

```
public class PhoneTypeChecker
{
    private readonly IManufacturer mfg;

    public PhoneTypeChecker( IManufacturer mfg )
    {
        this.mfg = mfg ?? throw new ArgumentNullExceptio(nameof(mfg));
    }

    public void CheckProducts()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( this.mfg.Name + ":\nSmart Phone: " + 
    this.mfg.PhoneFactory.GetSmart().Name() + "\nDumb Phone: " + this.mfg.PhoneFactory.GetDumb().Name() );
    }
}
```

Then the `Main` method would be redone as:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IManufacturerRepository repo = new ActualIManufacturerRepository();
    List<IManufacturer> mfgs = repo.GetManufacturers();

    PhoneTypeChecker checker = new PhoneTypeChecker( mfgs.Single( m => m.Name == "Samsung" ) );

    checker.CheckProducts();

    Console.ReadLine();

    checker = new PhoneTypeChecker( mfgs.Single( m => m.Name == "HTC" ) );

    checker.CheckProducts();
    Console.ReadLine();

    checker = new PhoneTypeChecker( mfgs.Single( m => m.Name == "Nokia" ) );

    checker.CheckProducts();
    Console.Read();
}
```

There are still other problems with this example - so do not take this an example of how to write well-architectured or production-quality code.

In short: only the implementation of `IManufacturerRepository` should be aware of the actual implementations of `IManufacturer` (and only the implementations of `IManufacturer` should be aware of the implementations of `IPhoneFactory`).