# Java Streams: Extend Built-In Collector

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I would like to know if it is possible to extend a built-in Java Stream collector from, the `java.util.stream.Collectors` class, as opposed to building a custom collector, from scratch, and therefore duplicating code already implemented in that class.

For example:
Let's say I have `Stream<Map.Entry<String, Long>> mapEntryStream`and I want to collect that to a map of type `Map<String, Long>`.

Of course I could do:

```
mapEntryStream.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

But let's say I would like keys and entries inferred like so:

```
//Not a real Java Collectors method
mapEntryStream.collect(Collectors.toMap());
```

So how do I make a collector, like the one above, that takes no arguments but invokes `Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)`?

Please note: This is not a question about whether such a collector ***ought*** to be made - only if it ***can*** be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a method to the `Collectors` class. However, you could create your own utility method that returns what you want:

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MoreCollectors {

  public static <K, V> Collector<Entry<K, V>, ?, Map<K, V>> entriesToMap() {
    return Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh that's what I meant by extend = add my own.

But yeah, this works. Thank you!

Comment: What makes this a factory method?

Comment: @jaco0646 Could be the wrong term. What would you call it? Utility method?

Comment: Yeah, I think _utility method_ is accurate here.

Comment: @jaco0646 Edited my answer. Though I still think it has at least some characteristics of a _factory method_.

Comment: You may be interested in [What are the differences between Abstract Factory and Factory Method patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739611/what-are-the-differences-between-abstract-factory-and-factory-design-patterns/50786084#50786084) I've spent too much time thinking about factories.