# Use Factory pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I try to use Factory pattern in this code. I have a method that take three arguments as input
and I need to `return` a factory that creates a classic Disney plot. Do I apply the given pattern correctly? And how return a factory that creates a classic Disney plot?

```
public PlotFactory classicDisneyPlotFactory(Character hero, Character another, Character without) {
        if (hero.equals("A") && another.equals("B") && without.equals("C")){
           return  .....;
        } else if (hero.equals("D") && another.equals("E")&& without.equals("F")){
            return ....;
        }else if (hero.equals("G") && another.equals("H")&& without.equals("I")){
            return ....;
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design pattern of Factory should be used like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DisneyPlotFactory dPlotFactory = new DisneyPlotFactory();
    APlot plot1 = dPlotFactory.getPlot("A", "B", "C");
    plot1.execute();
    BPlot plot2 = dPlotFactory.getPlot("G", "H", "I");
    plot2.execute();
}
```

What you did with `classicDisneyPlotFactory` should return a Plot and not a PlotFactory, like this:

```
public class DisneyPlotFactory { 
    public DisneyPlot getPlot(Character hero, Character another, Character without) {
        if (hero.equals("A") && another.equals("B") && without.equals("C")){
           return new APlot();
        } else if (hero.equals("D") && another.equals("E")&& without.equals("F")) {
            return new BPlot();
        }else if (hero.equals("G") && another.equals("H")&& without.equals("I")) {
            return new CPlot();
        }
        
    }
}
```

You can create the factory just every other class, the factory should expose the method to get the `DisneyPlot` generated from your parameters.

Comment: Note this is not a pattern from the GoF book. Head First Design Patterns calls this a "Simple Factory".

Comment: Oh thanks, could you answer with the correct Factory implementation? I would like to see the difference with the Simple Factory.

Comment: One implementation is no more correct than the others. There are just many kinds of factories. The two from the GoF book are described thoroughly in [What are the differences between Abstract Factory and Factory Method design patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739611/what-are-the-differences-between-abstract-factory-and-factory-design-patterns) There are other factory patterns in other books, such as Simple Factory in HFDP.