# headfirst design pattern, does abstract factory pattern includes factory pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I've been reading the "Head First Design Patterns" book and came across a question regarding the relationship between the Abstract Factory Pattern and the Factory Pattern. I'm trying to understand if the Abstract Factory Pattern includes the Factory Pattern as a concept, and what the differences between them are.

From what I've gathered so far, the Factory Pattern is all about creating individual objects, while the Abstract Factory Pattern focuses on creating families of related objects. Is this a correct understanding, or am I missing something?

I would appreciate it if someone could clarify the relationship between these two patterns, how they interact, and in what scenarios one might be more suitable than the other. does the abstract factory pattern include the factory pattern ?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between Abstract Factory and Factory design patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739611/what-are-the-differences-between-abstract-factory-and-factory-design-patterns) Please read through the top four answers. This is one of the most commonly repeated questions in the area of design patterns.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've read through the article you provided, but I still have some uncertainty regarding the Abstract Factory Pattern. 

My question is whether the Abstract Factory Pattern inherently employs the Factory Design Pattern as a part of its implementation. I'd like to understand if the Abstract Factory Pattern typically incorporates the Factory Pattern for creating its related objects, and if so, how these two patterns are interconnected in practice.