# headfirst design pattern, does abstract factory pattern inherently employs factory pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I've read through this article.
[What are the differences between Abstract Factory and Factory design patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739611/what-are-the-differences-between-abstract-factory-and-factory-design-patterns)

but I still have some uncertainty regarding the Abstract Factory Pattern. My question is whether the Abstract Factory Pattern inherently employs the Factory Design Pattern as a part of its implementation. I'd like to understand if the Abstract Factory Pattern typically incorporates the Factory Pattern for creating its related objects, and if so, how these two patterns are interconnected in practice.

Comment: I recommend accepting the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50786084/1371329) that these two patterns are unrelated. While this answer contradicts the GoF book, in more than ten years of searching, I have never seen a coherent explanation of how Abstract Factory is implemented by Factory Methods in a way that preserves any meaningful definition of what a Factory Method is. The book itself is vague and contradictory on this point. What you will discover researching this question is myriad references to nonsense ideas, like a "factory of factories", invented outside the GoF book.

Comment: I think the reason I was curious about whether the abstract factory pattern uses the factory pattern internally was because Platform factory was created based on inheritance in the article below. When I read the article below about this part, it said that this part could be replaced with the prototype pattern, and I realized that what I thought was actually wrong. Thank you for your kind notice.

https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory

Answer (score 0):

In the  Abstract Factory pattern, the interface `AbstractFactory` contains one or more "create" methods, which have the responsibility of creating objects of a certain type, usually called "products". However, those are not "factory methods", since they don't make a decision which concrete product they have to create. So no, the concrete factories don't employ factory methods in their implementation.

This decision for the specific group of concrete products is usually made at a different place: at the place where a specific derivation of `AbstractFactory` is chosen - and **that is where a factory method is required** - not for creating the products, but for creating the concrete factories themselves.

Comment: The GoF Abstract Factory Pattern always contains more than one method. Each method returns a different Product and the GoF refer to the collection of Products as a "family". The purpose of the GoF Abstract Factory Pattern is to enforce a constraint (e.g. a theme) across a family of Products (page 88). The GoF claim that, "The most common way to [implement Abstract Factory] is to define a factory method for each product." (page 90) However, the GoF also claim that, "Factory methods are usually called within Template Methods." (page 116) Reconciling these statements leads down a rabbit hole.

Comment: @jaco0646: - It can make perfectly sense to have just one creation method in the AbstractFactory interface. The examples in the books contain always more than one method to make the purpose more clear, but a "family of Products" can also be a set of product objects of the same type, created by one method.

Comment: Not in the GoF book it can't. This confuses many people, because typically in OOP the word "family" means inheritance hierarchy. In the GoF Abstract Factory Pattern it means something different, always. On this point at least, they are consistent.

Comment: I think the reason I was curious about whether the abstract factory pattern uses the factory pattern internally was because Platform factory was created based on inheritance in the article below. When I read the article below about this part, it said that this part could be replaced with the prototype pattern, and I realized that what I thought was actually wrong. Thank you for your kind notice. 

sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory